# Wrap text in tooltip in Flex2

Tags: apache-flex, flex2

How to wrap the text in tooltip property of any container(canvas, vbox) available in flex?Also please let me know how to access the textfield property of a Tooltip Class so that the "wordwrap" feature could be accessed.

Answer (score 0):

For any `UIComponent` based item you can set the `toolTip` property to get a mouse-over tooltip.

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=tooltips_3.html

ToolTips support styles, width values and so on so you can force word wrapping, colors, etc.